# Как сделать так, чтобы update() работал корректно?

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, pyqt, qpropertyanimation

На первый взгляд, если запустить программу все работает корректно, но в одном из **`10`** случаев `update` ломает программу, а точнее не работает.

Анимация застывает, а вторая фигура не появляется (если скрыть окно и выбрать снова - то все отобразилось, как будто *`update`* нет). Убрать его не получиться - пропадет анимация появления фигуры.

Я пробовал разбить все это на большое количество потоков, но ничего не вышло, может потому что я делал что-то не так?

Как можно исправить такую ошибку? 
При этом интерпретатор не выдает никаких ошибок.

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuick
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtGui import *
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    
    x = -340
    class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    
        def paintEvent(self, e):
            if self.flagPaintEvent:   
                painter = QPainter(self)
                painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(100, 250, 250), 1, Qt.SolidLine))
                painter.setBrush(QColor(250, 250, 250))
                painter.drawRect(90, 110, 340, 280)
            if self.flag2PaintEvent:
                painter2 = QPainter(self)
                painter2.setPen(QPen(QColor(110, 250, 250), 1, Qt.SolidLine))
                painter2.setBrush(QColor(250, 250, 250))
                if x <= 110:
                    painter2.drawRect(480, x, 340, 280)
                else:
                    painter2.drawRect(480, 110, 340, 280)
            self.update()
    
        def __init__(self):
            QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
            self.setUpdatesEnabled(True)
    
            self.flagPaintEvent = True
            self.flag2PaintEvent = False
    
            self.lockpx = QtGui.QPixmap('lock_1f512-2.png')
    
            self.namelockpic = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
            self.namelockpic.setPixmap(self.lockpx)
            self.namelockpic.setScaledContents(True)
            self.namelockpic.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 190, 20, 20))
            self.namelockpic.hide()
    
            def update_values():
                global x
                if x <= 110:
                    x += 90
                else:
                    return
    
            self.timer = QTimer(self)
            self.timer.timeout.connect(update_values)
    
            self.Button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("OK", self)
            self.Button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 305, 115, 30))
            self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.button1_click)
    
        def button1_click(self):
    
            self.animlock = QPropertyAnimation(self.namelockpic, b'geometry')
            self.animlock.setDuration(1000)
            self.animlock.setStartValue(QRect(380, 170, 20, 20))
            self.animlock.setEndValue(QRect(380, 190, 20, 20))
            curve = QEasingCurve()
            curve.setType(QEasingCurve.OutElastic)
            self.animlock.setEasingCurve(curve)
    
            if not self.namelockpic.isVisible():
                self.animlock.start()
    
            for each in [self.namelockpic]:
                each.show()
            self.showBlock2()
    
        def showBlock2(self):
            global x
            if self.flag2PaintEvent == False:
                x = -340
                self.timer.start(3)
            self.flag2PaintEvent = True 
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        mw = MainWindow()
        mw.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
        main()
```

Бьюсь над этой проблемой уже несколько часов, заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Уберите `self.update()` из paintEvent и перенесите в метод, чтобы вызывает таймер. `self.update()` вызывает перерисовку т.е. paintEvent, а по смыслу должно так: изменили данные, вызвали перерисовку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что понял, что должно происходить, но я вашу задачу увидел так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuick
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
#?        self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
        self.resize(900, 600)

        self.flagPaintEvent = True
        self.flag2PaintEvent = False
        self.x = -340                                                       # +

        self.lockpx = QtGui.QPixmap('Ok.png')                               # Ok.png

        self.namelockpic = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)                           
        self.namelockpic.setPixmap(self.lockpx)
        self.namelockpic.setScaledContents(True)
        self.namelockpic.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 190, 20, 20))
        self.namelockpic.hide()

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_values)  # self.

        self.Button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start", self, clicked=self.button1_click)
        self.Button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 305, 115, 30))
        self.button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Clear", self, clicked=self.button2_clear) # +
        self.button_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 305, 115, 30))

    def update_values(self):
        # print(f"self.x={self.x}")
        if self.x <= 110:
            self.x += 5          #90
        else:
            self.timer.stop()
        self.update()                                                                     # +

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.flagPaintEvent:   
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(100, 250, 250), 3, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.setBrush(QColor(250, 250, 250))
            painter.drawRect(90, 110, 340, 280)

        if self.flag2PaintEvent:
            painter2 = QPainter(self)
            painter2.setPen(QPen(QColor(110, 250, 250), 1, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter2.setBrush(QColor(250, 250, 250))
            if self.x <= 110:
                painter2.drawRect(480, self.x, 340, 280)
            else:
                painter2.drawRect(480, 110, 340, 280)
#-       self.update()

    def button1_click(self):
        self.animlock = QPropertyAnimation(self.namelockpic, b'geometry')
        self.animlock.setDuration(4000)
        self.animlock.setStartValue(QRect(380, 170, 20, 20))
        self.animlock.setEndValue(QRect(380, 305, 20, 20))        # (380, 190, 20, 20)
        self.animlock.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutElastic)

        if not self.namelockpic.isVisible():
            self.animlock.start()                                 
            self.namelockpic.show()                               # +

        self.showBlock2()

    def showBlock2(self):
        if self.flag2PaintEvent == False:
            self.x = -340
            self.timer.start(15)               # 3
        self.flag2PaintEvent = True 

    def button2_clear(self):
        self.namelockpic.hide()
        self.flag2PaintEvent = False
        self.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]